# Окрашивание текста в TetBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

При окрашивании текста в TextBlock с помощью TextRange в TextBlock появляется новая строка, если окраска произошла 2-ух и более строк в разный цвет. Цвета и диапазон беру из базы данных.
Код и пример неправильной работы ниже.

```
        public void ChangeColorText(DependencyObject container, DataSet dataSet)
        {
            TextPointer start_position = null;
            TextPointer end_position = null;

            DataTable ColorDataTable = dataSet.Tables[dataSet.Tables.Count - 1];

            if (container is TextBlock)
            {
                start_position = ((TextBlock)container).ContentStart;
                end_position = ((TextBlock)container).ContentStart;
            }
            else if (container is FlowDocument)
            {
                start_position = ((FlowDocument)container).ContentStart;
                end_position = ((FlowDocument)container).ContentStart;
            }
            
            TextRange[] coloredTextRanges = new TextRange[ColorDataTable.Rows.Count];
            for(int i = 0; i < coloredTextRanges.Length; i++)
                coloredTextRanges[i] = new TextRange(start_position, end_position);

            int textRangeIndex = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in ColorDataTable.Rows)
            {
                var cells = dataRow.ItemArray; 

                DataRow allTextDataRow = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                string text = allTextDataRow[cells[3].ToString()].ToString();

                if (container is TextBlock)
                {
                    if(textRangeIndex == 0)
                        ((TextBlock)container).Text = text;
                    start_position = ((TextBlock)container).ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset((int)cells[0]);
                    end_position = ((TextBlock)container).ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset((int)cells[1] + 1);
                }
                else if (container is FlowDocument)
                {
                    if (textRangeIndex == 0)
                        ((TextBlock)container).Text = text;
                    ((FlowDocument)container).Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(text)));
                    start_position = ((FlowDocument)container).ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset((int)cells[0]);
                    end_position = ((FlowDocument)container).ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset((int)cells[1] + 1);
                }
                
                coloredTextRanges[textRangeIndex] = new TextRange(start_position, end_position);
                coloredTextRanges[textRangeIndex].Text = (text[(int)cells[0]-1] == '\n' && textRangeIndex == 0) ? text.Substring((int)cells[0], (int)cells[1] - (int)cells[0]) : "\n" + text.Substring((int)cells[0], (int)cells[1] - (int)cells[0]);//textRangeIndex > 0 ? (int)cells[1] - (int)cells[0] - 2 : (int)cells[1] - (int)cells[0]
                coloredTextRanges[textRangeIndex].ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString((string)cells[2]));
                textRangeIndex++;
            }
        }
```

[image: Пример неправильного поведения]

По итогу все стало выглядеть вот так:

```
        public class RowColorModel
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
        }

        public class RowColorReader
        {
            public List<RowColorModel> coloredRows { get; set; }

            void GetTextFromDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
            {
                this.coloredRows = new List<RowColorModel>();

                List<DataTable> contentDataTables = new List<DataTable>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables.Count - 1; i++)
                    contentDataTables.Add(dataSet.Tables[i]);

                foreach (DataTable contentDataTable in contentDataTables)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow contentDataRow in contentDataTable.Rows)
                        foreach (var cell in contentDataRow.ItemArray)
                            foreach (string str in cell.ToString().Split('\n'))
                                this.coloredRows.Add(new RowColorModel
                                {
                                    Text = str.Replace('\r', ' ')
                                });
                }
            }
            public void ToFormColoredTextOnDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
            {
                GetTextFromDataSet(dataSet);
                DataTable coloredDataTable = dataSet.Tables[dataSet.Tables.Count - 1];

                foreach(var contentItem in this.coloredRows)
                    contentItem.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

                foreach (DataRow dataRow in coloredDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    var cells = dataRow.ItemArray;
                    coloredRows[(int)cells[0]].Color = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString((string)cells[1]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, не могу отыскать ошибку в коде. Если нужны просто цветные строчки, то покажу самое простое решение, почти без привязок.

Можно создать класс модели данных, готовых для отображения.

```cs
public class RowModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }
}
```

Можно создать список

```cs
List<RowModel> items = new List<RowModel>();
```

Можно его наполнить, так же в цикле, как вы выводите данные, только здесь без заморочек с контролами

```cs
items.Add(new RowModel
{
    Text = ...
    Brush = ...
});
```

Можно создать представление этого списка в интерфейсе

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Brush}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

И просто закинуть этот список в представление

```cs
myItemsControl.ItemsSource = items;
```

Выглядеть должно точно так же как на скриншоте.

Comment: Обязательно попробую. А у Вас нет идей почему так происходит? Если я окрашиваю 1 строку в TBто он все отображает корректно. При 2ух он вставляет на след строку 2 символа из последней окрашенной строки. При 3ех вставляет 6 символов. Пытался избавится от этого используя тернарный оператор, но это помогло только для 2ух окрашиваемых строк.

Comment: @WizardCore я никогда не работал из шарпа напрямую с контролами,мне сложно читать ваш код без возможности запустить отладку. Но не думаю, что проблема с окрашиванием. Скорее всего имеет место быть алгоритмическая ошибка.

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой, что текст не отображается в TextBlock

Comment: Я формирую список в функции класса, а далее возвращаю ItemsControl, и уже в событии присваиваю для ItemsControl.ItemSource для TextBlock, то что вернул из функции. Проверял список, он заполняется, но отображения содержимого на форме нет. Можете указать в чем проблема? Комменты сильно ограничены по символам поэтому не вставлял код, при необходимости могу добавить.

Comment: @WizardCore Вы можете вставить код в конец вопроса, я там посмотрю. `{ get; set; }` не забыли в классе сделать? К полям привязки не работают, только к свойствам.

Comment: нашел ошибку, в форме не убрал margin, из за этого TextBlock не отображался.

Comment: @WizardCore посмотрел код, все смешалось у вас. Вы перепутали строку и список строк. `RowColorModel` - это одна строка, предназначенная для одного текстблока. В ней не должно быть больше никакого кода. Как у меня в ответе, всё. Все методы работы со списком унесите оттуда. Если хотите, заведите отдельный класс `RowColorReader` и там работайте со списком. Модель - это только данные. Вы создаете объект с двумя свойствами и скармливаете его интерфейсу. Этот объект содержит только данные для одного текстблока и больше ничего. 1 текстблок = 1 модель. Список текстблоков = список моделей.

Comment: @WizardCore можете откатить правку поста назад, убрать код, там есть история редактирования, нажмите на "изменен...минут назад".

Comment: спасибо за замечание, я думаю, мне стоит его учесть и переписать код. Так будет проще с ним работать в будущем.

Comment: с чем может быть связано, что в TextBlock отображается окрашенной только последняя окрашенная строка, а не все. А еще хотелось бы узнать есть ли у Вас какие либо замечание по поводу написания моего кода, хотелось бы услышать.

Comment: @WizardCore быть может вот это условие `if ((int)cells[0] == contentStringIndexCount)` не срабатывает, поменяйте в нем черный на какой-нибудь другой. Кстати это проще сделать так `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)`, чем через конвертер и вообще вместо черного можете использовать `null`. Используйте отладку, выполняйте код пошагово, это проблема в вашем коде, точно не на стороне WPF.

Comment: Да вы были правы, переписал код и заодно убрал большую вложенность. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: @WizardCore отлично. Я почистил старый код из поста.

Comment: @WizardCore вот этот лишняя работа `List<DataTable> contentDataTables`, можно просто например вот так, чтобы исключить последнюю таблицу `foreach (DataTable contentDataTable in dataSet.Tables.Take(dataSet.Tables.Count - 1))`, поизучайте Linq.

Comment: это отличная идея, спасибо большое